# How can I get an aria label from React-Calendar using Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have a test where I need to set the date on a React-Calendar using their date-picker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar). The only element in the dom that will let me get the date accurately is the aria-label, which includes the full date, e.g., aria-label="August 12, 2020". Since the calendar may not include the date in the current view, I need a conditional test that first finds whether or not aria-label="August 12, 2020" exists in the dom. If not, I need the test to click the next month button and then click the date.

Here is the code I am working with:

```js
cy.get('.react-calendar').then(($reactCal) => {
            if ($reactCal.val().includes(`August 12, 2020`)) {
                cy.get(`abbr[aria-label="August 12, 2020"]`).click()
            }
            else {
                cy.get('.react-calendar__navigation__next-button').click()
                cy.get(`abbr[aria-label="August 12, 2020"]`).click()              
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 25):

```
cy.get(`[aria-label="August 12, 2020"]`).click()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you might have problems when aria-label changes with localization