# How to click on an aria label using Cypress automation?

Tags: reactjs, automation, frontend, cypress, onclicklistener

I am trying to automate a button click functionality using the cypress automation framework. The application source code is written in React.js, and the element I am trying to click is a button with pseudo code.
Here is the source code of the button written in react code.

```
<form class="search" action="/search?q=somevalue">
    <button type="button" aria-label="Submit search" class="ms-search__form-submitSearch msc-btn">
    ::before
    </button>
</form>
```

Here is the automation code I am trying to use to get the element to click

```
cy.get('[aria-label="Submit search"]').click()
```

However the click did not work, I also tried

```
cy.get('[aria-label="Submit search"]').click('{force:true}')
Cy.get('[aria-label="Submit search"]').trigger('mousedown')
```

None of this worked, no events were fired when the button is clicked. When I manually click on the button it works fine.

Comment: That doesn't actually create a pseudo element, just a button with the text `::before`. Your Cypress command should work. Please add the runtime HTML for the element.

Comment: What is the error message you get with your attempts? Maybe the computed styling is changing the button?

Comment: An example for selecting an aria label in cypress, so it can work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264003/how-can-i-get-an-aria-label-from-react-calendar-using-cypress I wonder if your selector is present when the cypress click happens?

Comment: Runtime HTML did not change, the problem is that no events were fired when clicked

Comment: Your `'{force: true}'` should not be a string - it should just be an object like `{ force: true }`. If you try it without the quotes, does it work?

Comment: yea the quotes are typo, I tried without quotes on {force:true}, it did not work, works with other code, also want to mention the form has an action attribute attached

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your button is inside a specific element:

```
<div id="external-wrapper">
    <button type="button" aria-label="Submit search" class="ms-search__form-submitSearch msc-btn">
    ::before
    </button>
</div>
```

you could do first identify the container and then find the "aria-label":

```
cy.get('#external-wrapper').find('[aria-label="Submit search"]').click('{force:true}');
```

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: Will find the button inserted in a wrapper as written above.
What's the matter?

Comment: Ok so force Click did not work, but cy.get('[aria-label="Submit search"]').type('{enter}')  works!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the event listener isn't attached at the time the test clicks.

See [Solve The First Click](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/solve-the-first-click/)

Add the [cypress-cdp](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-cdp) package and try with `cy.hasEventListeners()`

```js
const selector = '[aria-label="Submit search"]';
cy.hasEventListeners(selector, { type: 'click' });
cy.get(selector).click();
```

---

As a quick check without the above package, add (temporarily) a hard `cy.wait(300)` before the click.

I have also seen situations where React hooks are not completing because the test has the JS thread, in which case all you might need is `cy.wait(0)` to make Cypress release the thread.